# Deserializing with JSON.net dynamically

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a transparent proxy that tunels the requests between the frontoffice and the backoffice, my transparent proxy has 4 methods(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) that makes requests to several services dynamically.
My problem is that i cannot deserialize a list or an object depending on the response.

One Object:

```
var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Object>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.DownloadData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InternalWebApiUrl"] + "/" + url)));

return Request.CreateResponse(result);
```

List of Objects

```
var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.DownloadData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InternalWebApiUrl"] + "/" + url)));

return Request.CreateResponse(result);
```

Is there any way to verify if the response is an array or just one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.DownloadData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InternalWebApiUrl"] + "/" + url)));

return Request.CreateResponse(result);
```

Comment: Awesome! It seems Object can be a list or a single object!

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the JSON using `JToken.Parse` first, and then determine what you're dealing with:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);

if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> d = token.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
}
else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    List<object> list = token.ToObject<List<object>>();
}
```

Alternatively if you don't actually care what you're working with, you could use the `JToken`.